# How to use Web Template in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site, web-template

I have created a Web Template named "My WebTemplate" in Visual studio 2010 and deployed successfully to `http://somesite`. Now in `http://somesite` web application. I want to create a site that uses "My WebTemplate" by going site settings -> create site. In create site dialog, I could not find "My WebTemplate". From where I can find this? so that I can use it for site creation.

Comment: Can you put code how your template is created? Thanks